# Why does assigning a null value from a ternary statement to a Boolean variable throw a NPE?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

I have a part of code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String trueValue = Boolean.TRUE.toString();
    String fieldValue = null;
    Boolean defaultValue = null;

    Boolean value = (fieldValue != null ? trueValue.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue) : defaultValue);

    System.out.println(value);
}
```

When `defaultValue` is not equal to `null` the code works fine, but when `defaultValue` is `null` the JVM throws a `NullPointerException`. This code was compiled using jdk 1.6.45.

Why did I get this exception?

Comment: Because in Java a boolean value can't be null.

Comment: @Titus but Boolean can boolean can't

Comment: what are you trying to do in ternary operator ??

Comment: @getlost you are right, the problem here can be resolved like this `new Boolean(trueValue.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue))`

Comment: Do a clean build and Check the stacktrace. `System.out.println(value)` looks like it throws a NullPointerException, as `value.booleanValue()` is taken for `Boolean value`, which is null.

Answer (score 15):

[Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says:

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type `T`, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `T`.

Answer (score 9):

It's the ternary operator. Because the first option `trueValue.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue)` is a boolean, it seems to assume the second option `defaultValue` is a boolean rather than a nullable `Boolean`. It's odd, but that seems to be what's happening. If you cast the first option to `Boolean`, the error goes away:

```
Boolean value = (fieldValue != null ? (Boolean) trueValue.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue) : defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [JLS: 15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type `T`, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `T`.

Aka: when the 2nd and 3rd operand are primitive and boxed reference type, the result is considered the primitive type. At the end of your operation you are boxing it again, but by then you have already tried to assign `null` to a primitive type - which isn't possible.

The signature of `String#equalsIgnoreCase` is...

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase
```

Comment: +1, though "already tried to assign `null` to a primitive type" would be better written as "already tried to **unbox** `null` to a primitive type", or perhaps as "already implicitly called `booleanValue()` on a `null` reference".